# System.Net.FtpClient with SSL\TLS - Timed out trying to connect

Tags: c#, ftp, ftp-client, ftps

I'm made a setup of FTP server (based on ubuntu\vsftpd).

I'm connecting this ftp server from the internet, so I'm activated the SSL security feature in the server.

In order to check that everything is OK, I'm made a test with FileZiLla -> it's working.
Log (from FileZilla):

```
Status: Connecting to ****:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   234 Proceed with negotiation.
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Command:    USER ****
Status: TLS/SSL connection established.
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS ********
Response:   230 Login successful.
Command:    SYST
Response:   215 UNIX Type: L8
Command:    FEAT
Response:   211-Features:
Response:    AUTH SSL
Response:    AUTH TLS
Response:    EPRT
Response:    EPSV
Response:    MDTM
Response:    PASV
Response:    PBSZ
Response:    PROT
Response:    REST STREAM
Response:    SIZE
Response:    TVFS
Response:    UTF8
Response:   211 End
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 Always in UTF8 mode.
Command:    PBSZ 0
Response:   200 PBSZ set to 0.
Command:    PROT P
Response:   200 PROT now Private.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/home/****"
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (*,*,*,*,*,*).
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Here comes the directory listing.
Response:   226 Directory send OK.
Status: Directory listing successful
```

Going back to my C# code...
I'm trying to connect my server with the following code, which based on [System.Net.FtpClient](https://netftp.codeplex.com/):

```
public PageDownloader()
        {
            this.Client = new FtpClient();
            this.Client.Host = FTP_HOST;
            this.Client.Port = 21;
            this.Client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FTP_USER, FTP_PASS);
            this.Client.DataConnectionType = FtpDataConnectionType.PASV;
            this.Client.EncryptionMode = FtpEncryptionMode.Explicit;
            this.Client.ValidateCertificate += Client_ValidateCertificate;
            this.Client.Connect(); // Exception- System.TimeoutException: Timed out trying to connect!
        }

        void Client_ValidateCertificate(FtpClient control, FtpSslValidationEventArgs e)
        {
            // Never rich here
            e.Accept = true; // Allow all - just for testing...
        }
```

I'm got this exception:

> System.TimeoutException: Timed out trying to connect!    at
>   System.Net.FtpClient.FtpSocketStream.Connect(String host, Int32 port,
>   FtpIpVersion ipVersions)    at
>   System.Net.FtpClient.FtpClient.Connect()

Someone know why it's happen? Why I'm should check?

Comment: Did you solve the issue? Having same issue with ftps.

Answer (score 6):

need to set DataConnectionEncryption to true when you set an EncryptionMode

```
this.Client.EncryptionMode = FtpEncryptionMode.Explicit;
this.Client.DataConnectionEncryption = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using FTP active mode (`FtpDataConnectionType.AutoActive`) and FileZilla is doing passive mode (sends PASV command, not PORT command). Try to use `AutoPassive` instead of `AutoActive`.

Comment: Checked. Same problem.

Comment: Could you add some protocol tracing to see whats going on (or capture traffic with wireshark, but then you should disable TLS with ftp).